# Zip Code Boundary Maps for Commercial Use?

Tags: web-mapping, zip-codes

I need images of cities with features, streets, zip code names and zip code boundaries.  For example, take this screen shot:

[image]

This is very close to what I need, except not every zip code name is listed in each boundary.  If I could get city images like this, with complete zip code names and that allows commercial use, that would be perfect.

I don't need zooming or tiling.  Static images like the above are perfectly fine.  I don't even mind capturing the images myself if there's a service that will let me get this data, provided I can use the images commercially.

Do you know of any sources? I googled, but what I found was either lacking some features (as in the above) or did not allow commercial use.

Comment: My problem in understanding this question is the term "pre-drawn maps".  Maybe if you updated the question to include a description of what you found, and why you discarded them as unsatisfying.

Comment: Excellent point -- a picture's worth a thousand words.  I updated the question; please let me know if there's anything else I can do to make the question more precise.

Answer (score 3):

[TIGER ZIP Code boundaries](ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2013/ZCTA5/) and [TIGER Streets](ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2013/FEATNAMES/)(sorted by FIPS codes) free from the U.S. Census Bureau and should have all the data you need.

Comment: I believe I have a copy of those.  I was looking for pre-drawn maps -- which I wasn't clear about in my question.  Sorry.  I updated the question to clarify.

Comment: I'm not too sure which software you use, but in ArcMAP you can easily bring all those shapefiles in, label the ZIP codes, then export a map.

Answer (score 1):

I found a source: http://www.maptechnica.com/

To use maps for commercial purposes, you have to buy pre-made or custom maps.  But to simply view zip code area maps, you can use their zip code area map feature: http://www.maptechnica.com/us-zip-code-area-map/zip/

If you type in any zip code (eg: 45030) it will show a zip code area map that includes that zip code -- and all zip codes are annotated.